# How to use htaccess/htpasswd with multiple users and logins

Tags: .htaccess, directory, .htpasswd

How do I add multiple users and login credentials such that multiple users can access a directory with their specific credentials? Let's say I want them all to be able to access the directory `/about/team/`

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd1
Require user user1

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd2
Require user user2

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd3
Require user user3
```

.htpasswd

```
user1: 123%%^sample-passwordHJGH&^
user2: 456%%^sample-passwordHJGH&^
user3: 789%%^sample-passwordHJGH&^
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a single auth block and use `Require valid-user` instead. For example:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /absolute/file-path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Note that the file-path for `AuthUserFile` is an absolute filesystem-path.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#lettingmorethanonepersonin

Comment: `Require valid-user` is what I needed. Thanks